# desaparecido registro de una tabla mysql

Tags: mysql

En una tabla de inscripciones para asistir a un evento ha "desaparecido" el registro 7. No sale en pantalla al hacer un volcado de la tabla con

```
$query="SELECT * FROM aligxager"; 

$results = mysql_query($query,$link) or die('Error en la petición SQL.');
$cont = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
    $cont ++;
    //Nom
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach($row as $field) {
    echo '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($field) . '</td>';
}
echo '</tr>';
}   
mysql_free_result($results);
mysql_close();
```

Hay alguna manera de averiguar que hay en el registro y como se produjo su "desaparición"

Comment: Yo miraría **directamente en la tabla** a través de PHPMyAdmin por ejemplo, si el registro 7 existe o no. Puede existir y estar en blanco, en ese caso no lo verías quizá dentro de un `<td></td>`. Además, ¿cuántos valores puede haber en tu bucle for each?, imaginemos que hay 1,000 interacciones por algún motivo... tendrías una fila de 1,000 columnas `<td></td>`entre las cuales quizá esté el registro 7. No te fíes nunca de tu `$query` si ves que te faltan datos. Verifica en el origen.

Comment: Soy nuevo en PHP. Mañana intentaré instalar PHPMyAdmin. También seria interesante hacer copias de seguridad de las tablas, supongo. Gracias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

si el registro no existe es difícil averiguar que había en ese registro sin una copia de seguridad.

El motivo más probable es que no se completase la operación, si estaba en una transacción, por ejemplo y hubo un error, ese registro no se graba pero el identificar de la operación no se recupera para otra operación, por lo tanto, el siguiente registro tendría un salto. Pero este comportamiento es normal, no tienes que preocuparte.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Sigo aprendiendo ;-)

Comment: ¿Cómo se hace una protección de una tabla mysql?
Gracias anticipadas.

Comment: A que te refieres con "proteger"?